# How to get full slug, including all parent pages

Tags: slug

I am trying for hours and I managed to get full slug for parent of sub-page when I am on 3rd level sub-page I can not get slug of the top parent page. Example
domain.com/top_page/sub_page/sub_sub_page

I need to get full slug 'top_page/sub_page/sub_sub_page'

I am doing this for language sites that are on sub-domains (individuals sites). These pages have same slug across sub-domains. So I want to link language site that when you are on some given page link to language site will take you to that page in that language (not home page of that language).

example of hyperlink to English language sub-domain:

```
echo '<a href="en.domain.com/'.get_FULL_SLUG).'">'English'</a>';
```

Is it possible to get slug of top parent when you are on third level page, sub-sub-page

Hope somebody can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would replace domain.com/top_page/sub_page/sub_sub_page with /top_page/sub_page/sub_sub_page

```
$path = str_replace(home_url(),'',get_permalink());
```

Comment: If I understand...you are suggesting to take current permalink and get full slug from there exclude current sub-domain from permalink and after create dynamic link on language flags. Short example on how it would be of great help...Thanks again!

Comment: If your home url for the english site is en.domain.com/ then removing the home_url, and then adding in say fr.domain.com to the start of the permalink, you'd have the new URL. Eitherway your question is not about 'full slugs' as that would be 'sub_sub_page' which isn't what you stated you want. This question is about permalinks.

Comment: I guess you are right...there are two questions: how to get full slug of the current page and how to replace domain so flags will link to related pages...Example: Contact page when you click on any language flag it would take you to contact page in that language, I will make sure that contact pages in all languages have same slug...Not sure which way would be the best to achieve it.

Comment: I've already answered that though, for en.domain.com/contact $path == '/contact', so your french link is "fr.domain.com".$path, your german "de.domain.com".$path etc etc etc

Comment: I guess you're wanting something you can directly copy paste without any effort?

Comment: Yes, thanks Tim. Can you please clairfy should I put very first code in functions.php and after code language links 

    echo '<a href="en.domain.com/'.$path).'">'English'</a>';

Comment: Actually this has worked...thank you Tom.

For other users this is what I have done:
1. insert in header.php following
<?php
$full_slug = str_replace(home_url(),'',get_permalink());
?>
2. Linked language flags using following code:
<?php Echo "<a href=http://pt.domain.com$full_slug>" ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/flags/pt.jpg" alt="" />Português</a>

Comment: I would rather go with Ciantic's answer below, but there is a function to convert a permalink to a relative URL: `wp_make_link_relative()`

Answer (score 8):

Directly using [get_page_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_uri):

```
$path = get_page_uri($post_or_id);
```

Result is e.g. `top-level-page/sub-page/current-page`. This function is used internally by get_page_link etc.

Comment: To get the current page you can pass `null` as parameter. `echo "Full slug: ", get_page_uri(null);`